# R cbind two dataframes of different length throwing error invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)

Tags: r, data-wrangling, rbind, cbind

I am trying to cbind two dataframes of different lengths.

```
Category = c("New", "New","New","New","Old","Old","Old","Old",
"Expired", "Expired", "Expired", "Expired")
Monthly_Dates= c ('Jan-2014', 'Feb-2014', 'Mar-2014', 'Apr-2014',
'May-2014', 'Jun-2014', 'Jul-2014', 'Aug-2014', 'Sep-2014','Oct-2014','Nov-2014','Dec-2014')
Monthly_Vals =   c(4,7,6,7,8,12,10,11,10,16,12,120)

monthly_df <- data.frame(Category, Monthly_Dates,Monthly_Vals)
```

```
Category = c("New","Old", "Expired",  "Expired")
Quarterly_Date= c ( 'Mar-2014', 'Jun-2014', 'Sep-2014', 'Dec-2014')
Quarterly_Vals =   c(4,7,6,7)

quarterly_df <- data.frame(Category, Quarterly_Date,Quarterly_Vals)
```

```
monthly_df = cbind(monthly_df, matrix(data = NA, ncol = ncol(monthly_df), 
nrow = nrow(quarterly_df) - nrow(monthly_df),dimnames = list(NULL, names(monthly_df))));
```

```
Combined_dfs <- data.frame(monthly_df, quarterly_df)
View (Combined_dfs)
```

When i try to `cbind` monthly and quarterly values it throws error, what am i doing wrong?

**Error**

```
Error in matrix(data = NA, ncol = ncol(monthly_df), nrow = nrow(quarterly_df) -  : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
   Category Monthly_Dates Monthly_Vals   Category  Quarterly_Date  Quarterly_Vals
1       New      Jan-2014            4   New       Mar-2014        4
2       New      Feb-2014            7   Old       Jun-2014        7
3       New      Mar-2014            6   Expired   Sep-2014        6
4       New      Apr-2014            7   Expired   Dec-2014        7
5       Old      May-2014            8
6       Old      Jun-2014           12
7       Old      Jul-2014           10
8       Old      Aug-2014           11
9   Expired      Sep-2014           10
10  Expired      Oct-2014           16
11  Expired      Nov-2014           12
12  Expired      Dec-2014          120
```

Comment: From the online doc: "The cbind data frame method is just a wrapper for data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)".  Columns of a data frame must have the same length (try `data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:3)`), so you *cannot do* what you are trying to do.  Instead you must pad the shorter data frame to have the same number of rows as the longer or truncate/filter the longer to have the same number of rows as the shorter.

Comment: Just change to `quarterly_df = rbind(quarterly_df, matrix(data = NA, ncol = ncol(quarterly_df), nrow = nrow(monthly_df) - nrow(quarterly_df), dimnames = list(NULL, names(quarterly_df)))); data.frame(monthly_df, quarterly_df)`. You are trying to append columns to the longer data frame. That doesn't make any sense. Also you changed `rbind` to `cbind`, why?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087227/r-how-do-i-cbind-two-columns-of-different-size-without-repeating-rows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077502/r-how-do-i-add-na-to-a-dataframe-where-column-values-are-missing I highly recommend to start your programming experience by learning the very basics by studying a course, a book, ...

Comment: @Friede I have updated the question with the outcome hence i am using `cbind` instead of `rbind` here the outcomes is different i am trying to merge the two dataframes together two create a new view.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment.  Another option is to `join` the two data frames in some way.  But the fundamental issue is the same: you cannot `cbind` data frames with differing numbers of rows.  So *you cannot do what you are trying to do* with `cbind`.  You *must* take a different approach.

Comment: @Limey I have tired something like `merge(monthly_df,quarterly_df,by="Category")` based on the answer but this just repeats the `quarterly_df` over and over to meet the length of `monthly_df` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893846/how-to-merge-two-data-frames-with-different-sizes

Comment: Well, a comment I wrote under your previous question: 
*What do you mean by join? – Friede 4 hours ago*.

Comment: Well, following my suggestion, just delete the `Category.1` column of `Combined_dfs`: `Combined_dfs$Category.1 = NULL`. At least you are mixing up `rbind`, `cbind`, and `merge`. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve: attempt, description, and expected output fall apart. Once again I highly recommend to start learning R from the basics.

Comment: Can you say more about your motivation/goal? If this is for output to an Excel sheet, or making an HTML output table, there are probably better approaches that don't require making a data.frame break its own rules.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like this, but I'm almost loathe to suggest it because I feel it still avoids an underlying problem...

```
library(tidyverse)

monthly_df <- monthly_df %>% mutate(Row = row_number())
quarterly_df <- quarterly_df %>% mutate(Row = row_number())

monthly_df %>% full_join(quarterly_df, by = "Row")
   Category.x Monthly_Dates Monthly_Vals Row Category.y Quarterly_Date Quarterly_Vals
1         New      Jan-2014            4   1        New       Mar-2014              4
2         New      Feb-2014            7   2        Old       Jun-2014              7
3         New      Mar-2014            6   3    Expired       Sep-2014              6
4         New      Apr-2014            7   4    Expired       Dec-2014              7
5         Old      May-2014            8   5       <NA>           <NA>             NA
6         Old      Jun-2014           12   6       <NA>           <NA>             NA
7         Old      Jul-2014           10   7       <NA>           <NA>             NA
8         Old      Aug-2014           11   8       <NA>           <NA>             NA
9     Expired      Sep-2014           10   9       <NA>           <NA>             NA
10    Expired      Oct-2014           16  10       <NA>           <NA>             NA
11    Expired      Nov-2014           12  11       <NA>           <NA>             NA
12    Expired      Dec-2014          120  12       <NA>           <NA>             NA
```

Note the "duplication" of the `Category` columns because they appear in both data frames and you apper not to want to join on them.  I introduce a `Row` column to each data frame so that the rows of the shorter df are bound to the corresponding rows of the longer.

If you want `Category` only from `monthly_df`, drop it from `quarterly_df` before `join`ing.

Comment: thanks, the reason to keep the duplicate `Category` is because `Quarterly_Date Quarterly_Vals`  have their own `Category`  If  i drop the `Category` for `quarterly_df ` `Quarterly_Vals` will lose their original `Category` that they come under.

Comment: But dropping `Category` from `quarterly_df` is exactly what you do do in your expected output...

Comment: sorry realised my mistake and have fixed the expected output.

Comment: In R, data.frames are meant to / expected to have unique names, and all columns are vectors with the same length. You are explicitly asking to break both of those rules, so the output will either not be a data.frame or will be a kludgey one that breaks the requirements of the ecosystem around it. It is possible to create output from R like this if you are, say, outputting to an excel sheet, or making an HTML table, but it seems like asking for trouble to force this into a data.frame.

Comment: e.g. from `?data.frame`: Duplicate column names are allowed, but you need to use check.names = FALSE for data.frame to generate such a data frame. However, not all operations on data frames will preserve duplicated column names: for example matrix-like subsetting will force column names in the result to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something completely different. Probably a basci appraoch involving `merge` (and friends). However, here an answer to your question.

```r
quarterly_df = rbind(quarterly_df, 
                     matrix(data = "", ncol = ncol(quarterly_df), nrow = nrow(monthly_df) - nrow(quarterly_df), 
                            dimnames = list(NULL, names(quarterly_df))))
combined = data.frame(monthly_df, quarterly_df)
combined$Category.1 = NULL
```

gives

```r
   Category Monthly_Dates Monthly_Vals Quarterly_Date Quarterly_Vals
1       New      Jan-2014            4       Mar-2014              4
2       New      Feb-2014            7       Jun-2014              7
3       New      Mar-2014            6       Sep-2014              6
4       New      Apr-2014            7       Dec-2014              7
5       Old      May-2014            8                              
6       Old      Jun-2014           12                              
7       Old      Jul-2014           10                              
8       Old      Aug-2014           11                              
9   Expired      Sep-2014           10                              
10  Expired      Oct-2014           16                              
11  Expired      Nov-2014           12                              
12  Expired      Dec-2014          120
```

Comment: Thanks it does fix the problem  but if  we do drop the `Category ` column that does mean that the `Quarterly_Date` and `Quarterly_Vals`  do not have the `Category` as all the `Quarterly_Date  , Quarterly_Vals` now coming under the `Category=New `, i would like to preserve their original `Category ="New","Old", "Expired",  "Expired"`

Comment: It matches your expected outcome (2024/03/01 19:47:00 UTC+1). As stated several times, most of what you have written is inconsistent. Since you are not responding to advices, I feel myself forced to stop helping now.